# Laravel, Find full address name with Coordinates lat and lng

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

How can I get full address and city if I have lat and long, I tried many solutions but doesn't work with me, I need to get the results in controller

```php
public function getaddress(Request $request)
{
    if(!empty($request->thislat))
    {
        $thislat = $request->thislat;
        $thislng = $request->thislng;

    }

    return Response::json(array(
        'thislat' => $thislat,
        'thislng' => $thislng,
    ));
}
```

Comment: You need to use API coz you need a large data and algorithm to do it

Comment: can you explain more

Comment: You can use like this https://opencagedata.com/api , you need lat long and your api key only .... But there is so many fantastic api on internet .You can research and test

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using the [Geocoder](https://github.com/geocoder-php/Geocoder#ip) package, which provides an easy interface to use many of the popular APIs, or geoip databases directly.

It's very easy to set up and use, and has a [laravel package](https://github.com/geocoder-php/GeocoderLaravel) as well.

```php
use Geocoder\Laravel\ProviderAndDumperAggregator as Geocoder;

class GeocoderController extends Controller
{
    public function getGeocode(Request $request, Geocoder $geocoder)
    {
        $result = $geocoder->geocode($request->getClientIp())->get()->first();
        $result->getCoordinates()->getLatitude(); // Lat
        $result->getCoordinates()->getLatitude(); // Lng

    }
}
```

Comment: Class Geocoder\Laravel\ProviderAndDumperAggregator does not exist

Comment: Did you install the package as per https://github.com/geocoder-php/GeocoderLaravel#installation?

Comment: not yet but are you sure this package will return the full address with city name by using lat and long